# Wrong data is been displaying under tabs mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a home page which displays multiple tabs.

I am trying to add tabs for the first tab 
    in the page and I am doing this using jquery and ajax calls where tabs counts depends on 
    the fetched data.

For Example, My home controller has details action which displays 
    products,manufacturers tabs and under products tabs depending upon the fetched dat
    I am displaying country tabs and the first tab is working fine and for the second tab
    it is fetching data from manufactrures tab and no data is been displayed under 
    manufacturers tab.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<EmsAdmin.Models.abc>" %>
```

abc Details
    
     
    
        abc Details
    <% Html.RenderPartial("abc", Model); %>

Products

<% if ((Boolean)ViewData["HasWTB"])
               // Do they have the Where to by product?
               { %>

Manufacturers

<% } %>

Reports

<% if ((Boolean)ViewData["HasInText"])
               { %>

Categories

<% } %>

REgions

```
    </ul>
    <div class="panes">
        <!-- Products -->
        <div class="pane">
            <div style="clear: both;">
                &nbsp;</div>
            <% Html.RenderPartial("Products"); %>
            <div style="clear: both;">
                &nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of products-->
        <% if ((Boolean)ViewData["HasWTB"])
           // Do they have the Where to by product?
           { %>
        <!-- where to buy -->
        <div class="pane">
            <div style="clear: both;">
                &nbsp;</div>
            <% Html.RenderPartial("Manufacturers"); %>
            <div style="clear: both;">
                &nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of where to buy -->
        <% } %>
        <!-- Request Reports see Reports.ascx-->
        <div class="pane">
            <div style="clear: both;">
                &nbsp;</div>
            <% Html.RenderPartial("Reports"); %>
            <div style="clear: both;">
                &nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of request reports -->
        <% if ((Boolean)ViewData["HasInText"])
           { %>
        <!-- In Text -->
        <div class="pane">
            <div style="clear: both;">
                &nbsp;</div>
            <% Html.RenderPartial("InText"); %>
            <div style="clear: both;">
                &nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of in text -->
        <% } %>
        <!-- Ranges or SubBrands -->
        <div class="pane">
            <div style="clear: both;">
                &nbsp;</div>
            <% Html.RenderPartial("Ranges"); %>
            <div style="clear: both;">
                &nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of ranges of SubBrands -->
        <!-- Ranges or Region -->
        <div class="pane">
            <div style="clear: both;">
                &nbsp;</div>
            <% Html.RenderPartial("Regions"); %>
            <div style="clear: both;">
                &nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of ranges of Regions -->
        <!-- Categories -->
        <div class="pane">
            <div style="clear: both;">
                &nbsp;</div>
            <% Html.RenderPartial("Categories"); %>
            <div style="clear: both;">
                &nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of Categories -->
           <!-- REgions -->
        <div class="pane">
            <div style="clear: both;">
                &nbsp;</div>
            <% Html.RenderPartial("REgions"); %>
            <div style="clear: both;">
                &nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <!-- end ofFilters -->
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    // Set the tabs to be tabs
    $(function () {
        // setup ul.tabs to work as tabs for each div directly under div.panes
        $("ul.tabs").tabs("div.panes > div");
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Would you be nice enough to show a little piece of code ?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but that looks like MVC 2 code.

There are plenty of jQuery examples of very simple tabs. This one uses the twitter bootstrap one with MVC3 and Razor.

```
@model Layout.Models.DataModel
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    //  show the first tab
    $('#homeTabs a:first').tab('show');
});    
</script>
<div class="container">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="homeTabs">
    <li><a href="#section11" data-toggle="tab">1.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section12" data-toggle="tab">1.2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section13" data-toggle="tab">1.3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="section11">
        @{
            Html.RenderPartial("Details.1.1", Model);
        }
    </div>
    <!-- section11 end-->
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="section12">
    </div>
    <!-- section12 end-->
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="section13">
    </div>
    <!-- section13 end-->
</div>
<!-- tab-content end-->
</div>
<!-- container end-->
```

Hope that helps